# В реальном времени подменить swf

Tags: swf

Здравствуйте!!!
Уважаемые, у меня к вам такой вопрос. Нужно в реальном времени подменить swf файл на сайте для предпросмотра. При загрузке сайта загружаются несколько swf файлов. *swf подгружаются с помощью другого* swf, то есть, прелауедером внутри себя. Все эти файлы присутствуют в кеше браузера.

После загрузки, нужно подменить любую из этих на свой *.swf файл. Как то нужно заставить браузер, загрузить файл, http://example.com/111.swf  или  сохраненную у меня на диске , допустим, "C:\111.swf" вместо  http://example.com/ 1.swf. 
Ясно, что все это будет видно только мне. Прочитал на форуме похожие темы.
Но увы… Я в Java не очень так разбираюсь, и поэтому мне нужен ваша помощь.

Я пользуюсь браузерами Opera и FF. В кеше браузеров видно, что каждому файлу поставлен в соответствие адрес. Свой url  просто так не привяжешь туда. Браузер  наверно  где-то  хранить информацию об url. Не смог найти эти места.
Просто так я свои файлы в кэш браузера файл поместить не смог. То есть, заменил одну из файлов в кеше на свой- без расширения. Но …
Прошу вас, посоветуете для этой задачи. Как и каким образом мне выполнить :
- поместит свои файлы в кеш браузера.
- что надо сделать, что и где надо написать для подмены. Свой url вместо url файла подмены.